# Acidic strength of 4-(tribromomethyl) benzoic acid vs 4-(trichloromethyl) benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

From what I leart from my teacher is that 4-(tribromomethyl) benzoic acid is more acidic than  4-(trichloromethyl) benzoic acid. But I'm not sure what the reason is.According to me 4-(trichloromethyl) benzoic acid should be more acidic since Cl will exert much stronger -I effect and also hyper conjugation effect than Br.